# Devise change password form not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, email, devise, passwords

I'm trying to implement the password reset functionality in an app, using Devise. I'm at a point where the "forgot password" link works (in that it sends the email), and the email contains the link to "Change my password".

The change password link works and sends you to a form (at the URL `http://localhost:3000/users/password/edit?reset_password_token=c7cKb4hMhSLRs72n9dYj`) asking for the new password (and to confirm it), but after typing in a new password and clicking "Chang my password", it redirects to `localhost:3000/users/password` and says "Please review the problems below:" and presents a from with one field for Email, and a button for "Send password reset instructions". This is, of course, the form for submitting your email to get password reset instructions, but it also has an error notice of "can't be blank", as if someone clicked the button with the field empty.

I used a tutorial to configure ActionMailer to send the email, which I thought was going to be the most difficult part of this process, but now I can't figure out why the form to change one's password is not working.

I'm very new to Rails, and this is my first time working with Devise and ActionMailer, so I apologize if I haven't included some needed information. Just let me know and I can add anything that helps.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think that actionmailer is the issue here, especially because you say it sends the email just fine.  It wouldn't show you the form otherwise. Can you share the controller code that resets the password?

Comment: That's what I was thinking too, but I don't know how to view the controller for passwords, since I think it's built in to Devise. I was able to show the Devise views by running `rails g devise:views`, but I don't think the same thing is possible to show the Devise controllers.

Comment: Can you show the `passwords#edit` then? Also what version of devise are you using?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I'm running 2.2. In my gemfile I have `gem 'devise'`, so I think it should be running the most current version (which I think is 2.2). I don't know how to show the `passwords#edit`. Doesn't that represent the path to edit the passwords? When I run `rake routes` in terminal, I do have `edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format) devise/passwords#edit`, though.

Comment: Ok, so I think I found the devise controllers [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/passwords_controller.rb#L42), and it has the following code for the edit method:
   `def edit
    self.resource = resource_class.new
    resource.reset_password_token = params[:reset_password_token]
  end `

Answer (score 8):

Ok, so with the help of someone at a Rails meeting tonight, I found out what the problem was. It didn't really have anything to do with the controllers or routes, but rather I had caused the bug by incorrectly adding some code to the form. Here's the **corrected** code for my form:

```
<h2>Change your password</h2>

<%= simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => password_path(resource_name),
         html: { method: :put, class: "pure-form pure-form-stacked" }) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <%= f.hidden_field :reset_password_token %>

  <%= f.input :password, label: "New password", autofocus: true, required: true %>
  <%= f.input :password_confirmation, label: "Confirm new password", required: true %>

  <div><%= f.submit "Change my password", class: "pure-button" %></div>
<% end %>

<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```

My problem was that instead of including the `class: "pure-form pure-form-stacked` line as a second key/value pair into `html: {}`, I had a second `html: {}` line.

In case that's not clear, I had this:

```
html: { method: :put },
html: { class: "pure-form pure-form-stacked" }
```

instead of this:

```
html: { method: :put, class: "pure-form pure-form-stacked" }
```

and for some reason, in the first version, only the second `html: {}` was being submitted with the form, so it didn't get processed as a `put` request.